# how to create values of type T in a generic

Tags: generics, swift5

This Swift 5 code will choose which version of `dbl` to invoke by matching the return type of `dbl` to the type of the variable receiving the return value:

```
func dbl(_ x: Int) -> Int {
    print("called Intdbl")
    return Int(x * 2)
}

func dbl(_ x: Int) -> Float {
    print("called Floatdbl")
    return Float(x * 2)
}

var intsum : Int = 0 
var floatsum : Float = 0 

intsum = dbl(2) // prints "called Intdbl" and assigns Int(4)
floatsum = dbl(2) // prints "called Floatdbl" and assigns Float(4)
```

What if I wanted to convert this to a generic function? I suppose it should like like so:

```
func dbl<T>(_ x: Int) -> T {
    return T(x * 2)
}

var intsum : Int = 0
var floatsum : Float = 0

intsum = dbl(2)
floatsum = dbl(2)
```

But this fails with the error:
`Non-nominal type 'T' does not support explicit initialization`.

And this:

```
func dbl<T>(_ x: Int) -> T {
    return T.init(x * 2)
}

var intsum : Int = 0
var floatsum : Float = 0

intsum = dbl(2)
floatsum = dbl(2)
```

Fails with error `Type 'T' has no member 'init'`

In general, **how can you use a generic type (like T) to create a new value, if not `T` or `T.init`?**

FWIW I assume that this would work in the special case where T represents a class or struct with an explicit `init`. But generics are supposed to work with built-in types too (IIUC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to constrain your generic type to conform to the `Numeric` protocol. BTW You don't need to initialize a new type:

```
func dbl<T: Numeric>(_ x: T) -> T { x * 2 }

let intDbl: Int  = dbl(2)         // 4
let floatDbl: Float = dbl(2)      // 4.0
let floatDbl2: Float = dbl(2.75)  // 5.5
```

---

If you would like to keep the parameter as integers only you can use `Numeric` exactly fallible initializer that takes a `BinaryInteger` but it might return nil:

```
init?<T>(exactly source: T) where T : BinaryInteger
```

---

```
func dbl<T: Numeric, U: BinaryInteger>(_ x: U) -> T? {
    guard let value = T(exactly: x) else { return nil }
    return value * 2
}

let intDbl: Int?  = dbl(2)     // 4
let floatDbl: Float? = dbl(2)  // 4.0
```